# Show version of tensorflow 2.4.1 in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

Using python 3.7, how do you print the version of tensorflow if you have tensorflow 2.4.1. None of the documented styles: 'tf. __ version__', tf.version, nor tf.version.VERSION seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one seems to be working for me:

`tf.__version__`

Run with Python 3.7.10 and Tensorflow 2.4.1 in a Colab Notebook

Alternatively, if you used pip to install Tensorflow, you could also use:

```
pip show tensorflow
```

Comment: I agree with you. This should work. the tensorflow docs for r2.4 says it should work. I am using Python 3.7.8 in Visual Studio 2019 and it gives the error "tf has no attribute __version__" Perhaps I should just move on to tf r2.5. I am hesitant to do that as new behavior in 2.5 may break something else.